# Java multithreading ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, concurrentmodification

I have several tests that run in parallel, and uses the method below. Please see the code below it throws ConcurrentModificationException occasionally. I cannot figure out how it can happen?

```java
private static MyObject myObject; 

public void setupMyObject{
    syncronized(this){
       myObject = Optional.ofNullable(myObject).orElse(SomeConfig.ofDefaults());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code? What you've shown is where you *think* the problem lies. However that may not be the case and furthermore, even if it turned out to be, there is no context to form an answer.

Comment: *That* code **cannot** throw `ConcurrentModificationException`. --- Besides, that code is really badly flawed: `ofNullable(myObject)` means that `myObject` can be `null`, and by it's very nature, *that* `orElse(...)` can never be effectual, because can only have an effect when `myObject` *is* null, which would make `myObject.ofDefaults()` throw a **`NullPointerException`**. Unless of course `ofDefaults()` is a static method, in which case the code should have been `MyObject.ofDefaults()`, using the class, not the instance, to qualify the method call, i.e. the code is flawed.

Comment: @Andreas  Sorry, that was a mistake . I corrected the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myObject` is a static variable, to lock it you need to put class object in synchronized. Your present implementation doesn't lock it properly.

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class Test {

    private static String myObject;

    public void setupMyObject(){
        synchronized(Test.class){
            myObject = Optional.ofNullable(myObject).orElse(SomeConfig.ofDefaults());
        }
    }

}
```